# 8 - How to programmatically add terms to an existing Node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

After loading a node with `Node::load` with an existing taxonomy field `abc` do I add a new term and save? Something like?

```
  $term = Term::load(123);
  $node->get('abc')->appendItem($term );
```

Comment: I think `$node->get('abc')->appendItem(['target_id' => 123]);` would work

Comment: Strange - it seems that my approach also work... still checking.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The code to set the value of reference entries is very tolerant and accepts the full array with target_id and/or entity keys, a skalar with the id and an object of the term, which is then used to retrieve the id and store it in the database. But it does not make sense in your case to load the term and pass it, when later it is only used to get the id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the correct long form, as in the comment of mradcliffe:

```
$node->get('abc')->appendItem(['target_id' => 123]);
```

You don't need to load the term, use the term id.

You can use shorter versions:

```
$node->abc->appendItem(['target_id' => 123]);
$node->abc[] = ['target_id' => 123];
$node->abc[] = '123';
```

Comment: For the last short form, is it really '123' as a string?

Comment: Is this documented somewhere officially? I tried to look this up on Drupal.org but without success

Comment: You can use both, string and int. There are magic functions in the object to use the itemlist as array and the fields in the shortened version.

Comment: Will this ignore duplicates? I'm prepareing an import script and an worried it will corrupt something if I run `$node->abc[] = '123';` multiple times during testing

Comment: You have to check yourself for duplicates, drupal does not do this.

Comment: How to check for duplicates? ItemList seems to not have a function to get item with value, so I think the only way would be to use ItemList::filter() or ItemList::getIterator() and loop over, then removeItem() if found.

Comment: @Rob, yes, you have to loop over the field values. You don't need to use getIterator() though, because the array interface works like a normal array and you can put the field object directly in a foreach loop

Answer (score -1):

Just check the following code, its a dummy code need to be test

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create([
      'type'        => 'article',
      'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
    ]);
    $node->set('myterm_field', 'NEW TERM');
    $node->save();
```

Comment: I don't think that entity reference fields are set using a string value.